# Printing in java only results in screenshot

Tags: java, printing, jframe, jscrollpane

I have used the code from this great website to help me with printing a JFrame:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html

However, when I pass it my JScrollPane or the JPanel that is inside the JScrollPane that contains other jpanels and swing components,it simply cuts off parts of the pane that is not shown when I print it... Is there a solution for this problem? Thanks for any help!

Comment: "*pass it my JScrollPane"*  Pass the components instead.  Put them all in a single panel and use that for the printing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson hi, even if I pass in the JPanel that I have put into my JScrollPane, it still cuts off a part of it.

Comment: Have you tried making the size of the jpanel larger?

Comment: The thing is that the JPanel is too large for it to be printed in its whole.